# Packaging microarch variants with Conan

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, conan

I’m working on a project that is distributed to customers
as a shared library packaged (among others) using a
[Conan](https://conan.io) repo. These packages use the default
instruction sets for the platforms: standard AMD64/SSE2 for
Intel machines and ARMv8+NEON+HF for ARM.

For internal use I would like to also support optimized
builds for certain common microarches such as Skylake (focusing
on Intel for now). Internal consumers are also assumed to
handle dependencies with Conan, but the packages must be kept
separate.

How would I express that difference in a Conan package?
[From this issue](https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/847)
I take it Conan upstream doesn’t support it so I’m looking for
ideas how to solve this. I’m thinking of expressing the
difference in the package name so instead of

```
requires = [ "my-fancy-lib/1.33.7" ]
```

the use will depend on:

```
requires = [ "my-fancy-lib-opt-skylake/1.33.7" ]
```

in their `conanfile.py`, however that makes no sense for
ARM and other arches; plus I’d have to declare `my-fancy-lib`
as conflicting with `my-fancy-lib-opt-skylake` etc. which
would result in a combinatorial nightmare when adding other
target arches over time. Ideally I’d want a means to express
to the consumer that both packages despite the different name
actually provide `my-fancy-lib` like e. g. with the
`Provides:` statements in RPM.

Comment: You can customize your settings, adding new entries, like tune, arch, etc: https://docs.conan.io/2/examples/config_files/settings/settings_user.html So you will be able to generate the same package, but with different package id, not mixing with a generic arm/intel package. The customer will need to have the same settings.yml file, that can be distributed by a git repo and installed with conan config command.

Comment: @uilianries: So this would amount to creating a new ``arch`` to replace ``x86_64``? I’d prefer them to continue using ``x86_64`` for their builds and opt into the AVX version of the package explicitly when selecting the dependency.

Comment: You can define ``micro`` subsetting to the ``x86_64`` architecture if you want to. It will require to expand all architectures in yaml, but this is doable. For further discussions and details, maybe the best would be a github ticket in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues

Comment: @drodri: I linked what I believe is the relevant ticket in the question: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/847 – Also ``settings.yml`` doesn’t appear to be part of the project but at least on my machine it’s located in the dotdir. I’m looking for a way to distinguish between the two  from the package side, without asking the user to modify their own setup.

Comment: ``settings.yml`` file is in the Conan home directory (typically ``<userhome>/.conan``, not in the current project. The way to manage custom settings for users is to manage them with ``conan config install``, where profiles, settings, remotes, etc can be put in a git repo or in an http server and be shared with users easily.